# Validate XML filename

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Is it possible to also validate an XML's filename? I want to fail validation if the file is not named `<componentType>-<name>.xml`, where componentType and name are elements in the XML.

Of course I could run some bash script using xpath, but here I don't have that option.

Comment: Can you show us real sample input/expected output?

Comment: @GillesQuénot given a file `<name>Gilles</name>` give me an XSD that will fail validation if the filename is not "Gilles.xml"

Comment: Maybe update your question to include that you are validating the XML during a Maven build and edit the tags to include maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using XSD directly (and I'm not sure why you would want to).

You could possibly use an XSD 1.1 assertion to test the value of base-uri(), but it's not going to be 100% reliable - whoever requests the validation has plenty of ways of failing to inform the validator of the document's location, or of misinforming it.

Comment: I'm simply trying to enforce a naming convention. I'm validating XML during a Maven build with https://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/index.html

Comment: Why this information are not **in your original post**?